# How to read language definition syntax for regular/nonregular languages

Tags: abstract, theory, regular-language, fsm, pumping-lemma

I am trying to understand a simple concept about Language definition.
Specifically when there are two strings in the language definition.
such as:

```
    Language F = ww | w ∈ {0,1}*
```

Can someone help me understand the syntax? It makes sense to me when there is only one w, the set notation containing w also confuses me.
Looking it up online/in the book didn't answer this specific question concisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this particular notation is telling you is that there is a language F of strings all the strings in F can be written in the form ww, where w is some string of binary digits. "ww" means that you take a string w and concatenate it with itself; so, if w=Patrick87, then ww=Patrick87Patrick87. Not all strings are of the form ww; for instance, consider "01". So, this definition tells us which strings are and which strings are not in F.

Comment: I'd suggest using an example of w=101 or something similar to avoid unnecessary confusion.